# Is it advantageous to rank documents based on their relevance to a base document

Tags: full-text-search, search-engine, theory, similarity

I am looking at ranking document based on their relevance to a reference document or a base document instead of the query . Would it be advantageous to use this approach or should i stick to using a query ?

Answer (score 0):

What I understand by your question is that you intend to rank documents based on similarity to some *other* document, which will be provided as an input by a user in your search engine.

It may be advantageous in case a user *already* has  *reference* document to provide to your engine, such as some research scholar looking for articles similar to one he/she is currently interested in, or someone interested in reading wants to get to know of books similar to the one he/she is currently reading (like amazon recommendations, ***but*** those are like Customers-Who-Bought-This-Item-Also-Bought-...)

As far as the issue of using this approach or using a query-based approach goes, I don't think most users would have any document or digital resource to provide an input. I would implement a query-based search, and have an option for *similar-document* search, so that those who need it may use it, like [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com/).